# Selenium C# select an element inside div

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, xpath, webdriver

Hello all I have a select where it was binded as follows in UI

```
<div class="choices form-group form-choices" data-type="select-one" dir="ltr" tabindex="-1" role="listbox" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
 <div class="form-control ui fluid selection dropdown" tabindex="0">
  <select lang="en" class="form-control choices__input" type="text" name="data[serviceAmpsDelivered]" ref="selectContainer" dir="ltr" hidden="" tabindex="-1" data-choice="active">
   <option value="6">&lt;span&gt;60&lt;/span&gt;</option>
  </select>
  <div class="choices__list choices__list--single">
   <div class="choices__item choices__item--selectable" data-item="" data-id="38" data-value="6" data-custom-properties="null" aria-selected="true" data-deletable="">
    <span>60</span>
    <button type="button" class="choices__button" aria-label="Remove item: '6'" data-button="">Remove item</button>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="choices__list choices__list--dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
  <div class="choices__list" role="listbox">
   <div id="choices--data-oa-item-choice-1" class="choices__item choices__item--choice choices__item--selectable is-highlighted" role="option" data-choice="" data-id="1" data-value="1" data-select-text="" data-choice-selectable="" aria-selected="true">
    <span>50</span>
   </div>
   <div id="choices--data-oa-item-choice-2" class="choices__item choices__item--choice choices__item--selectable " role="option" data-choice="" data-id="2" data-value="6" data-select-text="" data-choice-selectable="">
    <span>60</span>
   </div>
   <div id="choices--data-oa-item-choice-3" class="choices__item choices__item--choice choices__item--selectable " role="option" data-choice="" data-id="3" data-value="2" data-select-text="" data-choice-selectable="">
    <span>100</span>
   </div>
   <div id="choices--data-oa-item-choice-4" class="choices__item choices__item--choice choices__item--selectable " role="option" data-choice="" data-id="4" data-value="5" data-select-text="" data-choice-selectable="">
    <span>150</span>
   </div>
   <div id="choices--data-oa-item-choice-5" class="choices__item choices__item--choice choices__item--selectable " role="option" data-choice="" data-id="5" data-value="3" data-select-text="" data-choice-selectable="">
    <span>200</span>
   </div>
   <div id="choices--data-oa-item-choice-6" class="choices__item choices__item--choice choices__item--selectable " role="option" data-choice="" data-id="6" data-value="4" data-select-text="" data-choice-selectable="">
    <span>400</span>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

I am able to select the div and the dropdown gets opened but I am unable to select the item

```
WebElement element= (WebElement)driver.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/app/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/app/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/app/div/div/div/forms-app/div/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]"));
Helper.JavaScriptClick(_driver, element);

WebElement elementValue= (WebElement)driver.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/app/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/app/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/app/div/div/div/app/div/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[4]"));
        Helper.JavaScriptClick(_driver, elementValue);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I got the solution after some trail and errors

```
WebElement ddlControl= (WebElement)_driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//select[contains(@name,'controlName"));
Helper.JavaScriptClick(_driver, ddlControl);
TimeSpan timeToWait = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10);
WebDriverWait waitForElemet = new WebDriverWait(_driver, timeToWait);
waitForElemet.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//div[contains(@id,'ControlId')]//following::span[text()='50']"))).Click();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to select item from dropdown list, You
can check the ID is unique for each elements if you use the parent tag as div and then following child.

`xpath` for item 1.

```
//div[@id='choices--data-oa-item-choice-1']/span
```

`xpath` for item 2.

```
//div[@id='choices--data-oa-item-choice-2']/span
```

and so on.

---

If you want to select a specific one you can parameterize the value.
Lets say you want to select `150` from dropdown list.

```
var itemval="150";
WebElement element= (WebElement)driver.FindElement(By.XPath($"//div[starts-with(@id,'choices--data-oa-item-choice-')]/span[text()='{itemval}']"));
Helper.JavaScriptClick(_driver, element);
```

Comment: Thanks will it work with contains or ends with? because the Id is dynamic and I can see the last text was constant like `item-choice-1` `item-choice-2` like that

Comment: I tried and got this error `stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document`

Comment: `choices--data-0j-item-choice-1` as after data- it is changing I tried this way `//div[starts-with(@id,'choices--dataserviceAmpsDelivered-`

Comment: But some how it is unable to select the element I tried this way `WebElement element = (WebElement)driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[contains(@id,'-item-choice')]//span[text()='150']")); Helper.JavaScriptClick(_driver, element);`

Comment: @Developer, It is possible to share the url?

Comment: Hi @KunduK I can but it is authenticated using Azure AD :(

Comment: Here is the html of that element seems we are using some additional css to show it as drop down https://jsfiddle.net/uw54bygo/

Comment: @Developer, `xpath` seems fine to me. Two things please check. 1) provided enough time to load the element, 2) scroll the page and reach the element and interact, If google it, you will get how to scroll the page element.

Comment: will try and see

Comment: I tried several ways but no luck

Comment: I found this ` Actions act = new Actions(_driver);
            act.SendKeys(Keys.Down).Perform();
            act.SendKeys(Keys.Down).Perform();
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            act.SendKeys(Keys.Enter).Perform();`